# React-native! Problem with @expo/vector-icons/Fontisno

Tags: android, react-native

Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto" from "node_modules/react-native-dynamic-vector-icons/lib/components/Icon.tsx"
How to solve this?

Comment: Remove node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me to install version 2.13.8

```
yarn add native-base@2.13.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Rollback to native-base 2.13.8 version

```
npm i --save-exact native-base@2.13.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Also on ios.
Add to package.json into scripts

```
"postinstall": "cp node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome.js node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto.js",
```